# Zend framework SEO friendly URL routing based on category/subcategory/product slug

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-framework-routing

I am developing a `Zend Application` in which I need to implement `slug based URL` as `Wordpress` does for its page/post. I have done it for `static pages`, its working fine as I need. Here is different scenario. I am trying route to corresponding module/controller.

**There are two things**

1. In my application, `Category/Subcategory` are there. eg:

   `cat1, cat2`

   `subcat11, subcat12, subcat21, subcat22, subcat23`
2. `Products` that are assigned to at-least one `subcategory`. eg:

   `product1, prdocut2, product3`

**Note : Category, subcategory, product name used in example are slug.**

The URL should be :

For Category : `http://domain.com/cat1`

For Subcategory : `http://domain.com/cat1/subcat11`

For Product : `http://domain.com/product1`

I have designed three controller for each. Listing are showing on their `Index` action.

`CategoryController, SubcategoryController, ProductController`

If I apply routing in application bootstrap, Website index page redirects to Category page.

```
$categoryrouter   = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/:categoryslug/',
                    array(
                        'module' => 'default',
                        'controller' => 'category',
                        'action' => 'index',
                        'categoryslug'  =>  'mobiles'
                    )
);

$chain->chain($categoryrouter);

$router->addRoute('categoryrouter', $categoryrouter);
```

May be it is duplicate question but I googled a lot and found nothing suitable answer to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

See this blog post for some info on how to do this: http://tfountain.co.uk/blog/2010/9/9/vanity-urls-zend-framework. You'll need two separate route classes - one for categories and one for posts.

You also seem to be using route chaining for just one route, which is unnecessary. Also be careful with terminology, your application has one 'router', which has many 'routes'.

Comment: Thanks, I have checked this link already. it is working well only for one slug (for category http://domain.com/cat1 and product http://domain.com/product1) but not for subcategory http://domain.com/cat1/subcat11. I have some static pages and customer pages. For which I used Route Chaining.

Comment: The principle is still the same for heirarchical routing, but in the match function of the route class you check the pathBits in a loop